# .htaccess rules to allow clean URLs along with index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I have a project with configuration to set with clean URLs (meaning without file extensions). Now, I am trying to configure a CMS for blogging in my project which is an MVC framework, so it includes `index.php` in its path. The platform's configuration doc provides a rewrite rule to disable index.php and have clean URLs but somehow their rules conflict with my current setup.

My current rewrite rules are as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Blogging platform's docs say, set it up as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am looking for an amalgamation of both where I have URLs without file extensions on my website along with proper configuration for the blogging platform as per their docs.

The blogging platform being used is [Anchor CMS](http://anchorcms.com).